# how to get data mysql with shimmer on android studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: Sample Image]
[image: Sample Image]
[image: Sample Image]

When I run on my phone it doesn't get the data on my database sql "Couldn't fetch the menu! Pleas try again."

here's my php code:

```
<?php 

require_once "../include/Constants.php";

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, description FROM newsfeed");

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $description);

    $newsfeed = array(); 

    //traversing through all the result 
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $id; 
        $temp['name'] = $name; 
        $temp['description'] = $description; 
        array_push($newsfeed, $temp);
    }

    //displaying the result in json format 
    echo json_encode($newsfeed);
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Instead, write up a [mcve] and post that as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

you have written `newsFeedDataList != null`  instead of that you should write

```
if (newsFeedDataList == null){
return ;
}
```